# How to extract everything after 1st series of numbers PL/SQL

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, regexp-substr

I want to extract everything after the 1st series of numbers.
For example, the outcome of 95a6 should be 95 and a6.
And the outcome of 9B2 should be 9 and B2

Comment: Huh?  Are you returning one value or two values?  How are you getting "95"?

Comment: The value is in 1 field, for example 263C2.
The outcome I want is are 2 values in 2 fields, which would be 263 in one field and C2 in the other field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `REGEXP_SUBSTR` for this:

```
SELECT str
     , REGEXP_SUBSTR(str, '\d+') AS substr1
     , REGEXP_SUBSTR(str, '[A-Za-z].*') AS substr2
FROM (
    SELECT '95a6' AS str FROM DUAL UNION
    SELECT '9 B2' FROM DUAL
) tests
```

Here `\d+` matches a sequence of digits and `[A-Za-z].*` matches a letter and everything after it.

[**Demo on db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=d32dfea571587a9bc3841c799f7bb7ce)

Comment: Can you explain please the difference between \d and \D ? and why you added `.` ?

Comment: And how can I remove all white spaces, if there is any?

Comment: You could simply `TRIM` the string before matching. Be advised that this is a very simple regex designed only to handle the examples you provided.

Comment: If I use trim it removes the white spaces but when I use REGEXP_SUBSTR to divide the column into 2 columns it still has white spaces.

For example:

the original input, which is 1 field, 95 a6 ----> output is '95' and ' a6'.
So still with whitespace

Comment: @bhr... my bad... TRIM ***after*** REGEXP_SUBSTR i.e. `TRIM(REGEXP_SUBSTR(...))`. Having said that, I recently added another example in my answer. Or change the second regexp from `\D.*` to `[a-zA-Z].*`. Lots of possible workarounds.